# jQuery bind event on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a small script that I would like to complete on change of value, on click, or on keyup on certain elements, but I *also* want it to happen on page load (or when the elements first load).

The code that I have now will do it, but doesn't do it originally on page load, you have to complete one of the 3 triggers first. Is it possible to do this without writing a new script?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.orderinput, .paymethod, .serverselect').bind('change click keyup', function(event) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your logic out, and put it into a separate function. Then call that function in your ready clause. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.orderinput').on('change click keyup', function(event) { myComplexFunc(event); } );

    var myComplexFunc = function(event) {
        console.log('Triggered');
    }

    myComplexFunc();

});
```

Comment: That's what I was hoping to not have to do, having 2 scripts. Is there any way to do it otherwise?

Comment: When you say this will cause you to have two scripts, what do you mean? This shouldn't require you to add more than 4 extra lines of code.

Comment: It requires me to duplicate all of the code that I have in the function, which just adds lines.

Comment: It doesn't require you to duplicate the code, no. You can put the code you have right now into its own function, and then replace it with your new function. Refer to the example code that I've posted for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Mike L, I would suggest you use `.on` instead of `.bind` as it is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document, see [this](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

If you want to avoid writing a separate function you can trigger an event after the event handler has been attached directly on the element like this:

```
$(".yourElementClass").click(); //or .change() or .keyup()
```